# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have seen the previous question but could not solve it. I am getting error while serving the ionic 2 application. Here is my code of call

```
 updateLocation(location) {
    let userInfo;
    this.storage.get(this.CURRENT_USER_KEY)
    .then(data => {
        if (data) {
            userInfo = JSON.parse(data);
            userInfo['latitude'] = location.latitude;
            userInfo['longitude'] = location.longitude;
            return this.httpClient.post(ENDPOINTS.BASE + ENDPOINTS.UPDATE, userInfo)
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log('update response: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
            });
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

and here I'm calling this function like this:

```
this.zone.run(() => {
            this.userService.updateLocation(position.coords)
            .subscribe(res => {      // here i'm getting this error
                this.groupLocation = position.coords;
            });
        });
```

Please help.

Comment: You're not returning anything from the method.

Comment: im returning check this `return this.httpClient.post(ENDPOINTS.BASE + ENDPOINTS.UPDATE, userInfo)`  @estus

Comment: No, you aren't. You're returning this from `then` callback. The method returns nothing and you can totally trust TypeScript on that.

Comment: how can i can get this done ? @estus

Comment: If you expect it to return an observable, you should return an observable. Since you're using a promise, you can wrap it with `fromPromise` and then merge http observable with `mergeMap`.

Comment: can it be a typescript version error ? @estus

Comment: if no then can u make function like u saying @estus

Comment: No, it can't be TS error, the error is in your code. It should be done like I've described, sorry, I don't have time to provide a solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comment, Try with following:

```
let promise = this.storage.get(this.CURRENT_USER_KEY)
    .then(data => {
        if (data) {
            userInfo = JSON.parse(data);
            userInfo['latitude'] = location.latitude;
            userInfo['longitude'] = location.longitude;
            return this.httpClient.post(ENDPOINTS.BASE + ENDPOINTS.UPDATE, userInfo);
        } else {
            return [null];// return array stream
        }
    });

 Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise)
      .flatMap((x: any) => x) 
      .subscribe(x => console.log('Observable resolved'+ x));
```